# Try to use an if elif else statement with an eval(input()) function

Tags: python

I am building an RPG style text based game in Python and I am stuck on a part. I am trying to ask for user input and use that in the code to select the players character and race. I have all the races as a class and the classes as a class.

Here is an example:

```
class Human:
    hp = 50
    dg = 10
    ar = .1
    cs = .05
    ak = 5
    ev = 0.1

class Elf:
    hp = 20
    dg = 20
    ar = .1
    cs = .2
    ak = 15
    ev = 0.15

def race_sel():
    y = eval(input("Select Race: Human, Elf").capitalize())
    return y

x = race_sel()

class Mage(x):
    hp = 80 + x.hp
    dg = 20 + x.dg
    ar = .15 + x.ar
    cs = .1 + x.cs
    ak = 40 + x.ak
    ev = .15 + x.ev

class Warrior(x):
    hp = 100 + x.hp
    dg = 20 + x.dg
    ar = .2 + x.ar
    cs = .1 + x.cs
    ak = 30 + x.ak
    ev = .15 + x.ev

def char_sel():
    y = eval(input("Select Class: Mage, Warrior").capitalize())
    return y

q = char_sel()
```

This semi works. In the console it asks the "String" then if I type, human or elf it `.capitalize()`s the input and sets `x` to the class selected. Then `x` is plugged into one of the classes, either `Mage(x)` or `Warrior(x)`. Then it adds `x.whatever` to the class that's selected.

Then the `char_sel():` function selects what class the character is playing.

The issue I have is I wanted to use an if else statement in the functions: `race_sel()` and `class_sel()` where if the user input is not "human" or "elf" then it prints "Invalid selection, try again", but it seems with `eval()` it automatically checks your input with all the Python classes you have in your code. Because `eval()` changes it away from a str type.

Could I take a string input in then convert it to the `eval()` type? I really am not very familiar with the `eval()` method. It was just something I found so I could call my classes with user console input.

I am sure there is an easier way to do most of what I am writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the appeal of using introspection to avoid repeating yourself. Don't use `eval()`, just check to see if the user's entry is in `globals()`.

```
def race_sel():
    prompt = "Select race: Human, Elf "
    race = input(prompt).capitalize()
    while race not in globals():
        print(race, "is not a valid race. Try again.")
        race = input(prompt).capitalize()
    return globals()[race]
```

For further not-repeating-yourself, derive all your classes from a base class, then use `isinstance()`  to make sure the user has actually entered a valid race. (Or you could put all your races *inside* a `Race` class, using the outer class simply as a namespace.) You can also dynamically generate your prompt using introspection, so defining a new race will automatically update the menus.

Comment: First off thank you for your' answer! I really like the idea of being able to add more classes and the prompt dynamically updates with it.

I also like the idea of using a class as a name space like:

class Races:
     class Human:
           ev = 1
etc...


I tried using isinstance() but I can't seem to figure it out fully. I am trying to check is "human" is in the class "races" then if true it returns it. if not prints "invaild"

Answer (score 1):

Using `eval` [is generally bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice). It's better to do this (it also solves your question):

```
def race_sel():
    while True:
        # the .lower() allows user to input hUmAn or something and it will still work
        type = input('Select Race: Human, Elf ').lower()
        if type == 'human':
            return Human
        elif type == 'elf':
            return Elf
        else:
            print('Invalid selection, try again')
```

Use a similar process for `char_sel`.

By the way, there is no such thing as an `eval` type. `eval` returns a typical Python object if successful (the type depends on the contents of the argument of `eval`).